# A problem related installation of kali 32 bits on Oracle Virtualbox

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

I recently tried to install Kali on my 32 bits PC and allowed 495 mb ram. After completion it told me to install necessary Kali meta packages. The metapakages are 94 percent installed. But the problem is that it is stuck there while installing `wpscan` . I waited for more than 2 hours but nothing is happening further . What should I do

Comment: Oracle virtual box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not satisfied the [minimum requirements](https://www.kali.org/docs/base-images/kali-linux-hard-disk-install/) for an installation of Kali Linux:

- A minimum of 20 GB disk space for the Kali Linux install.
- RAM for i386 and amd64 architectures, **minimum: 1GB**, recommended: 2GB or more.
- CD-DVD Drive / USB boot support

Even for the smallest and most cut-down [Mini ISO](https://www.kali.org/docs/base-images/kali-linux-network-mini-iso-install/) installation you have still not satisified those minimum requirements:

- For i386 and amd64 architectures, a **minimum of 512MB RAM**.

Comment: Sir this time I gave it 1.5 GB RAM and 150 GB disk space still it got stuck at wpscan

Comment: Please update your question to tell us which version of Kali you have installed, and where you got it from.

Comment: Thanks sir it worked but now I am facing another problem. The installation is complete but when I launch kali I just see a kali image with black background with no options. Can't do anything on it can you please help

Comment: @NooneNoone are you familiar with Linux systems in general, or is Kali your first try?

Comment: Kali is my first try

Comment: Ok. I'd recommend you use a more friendly distribution. Kali isn't for beginners. Maybe try Mint, Ubuntu or maybe Fedora.

Comment: Ok but I heard for pentesting kali is best. I want to become cyber security expert.

Comment: All the tools are available on every distribution. Learn to walk before you try to run.

Comment: Thanks sir I will take care of it